# Real estate agent wants a loan introduction letter

Tags: united-states, mortgage, real-estate, first-time-home-buyer

I was talking to a real estate agent (USA, CA bay area) who told me that I need to not only fill out a loan app, w2, and account statements but also write a introduction letter for the lender. I've never heard of this is it common?

When searching the internet I haven't seen any examples of this. I see examples of cases where people have been in financial peril or needed to explain anomalous finances but never for a simple mortgage application.

I've talked to other real estate agents who have not mentioned this. Is this a red flag? Why can I not find examples on the internet. I searched mortgage application introduction and I just found bank introduction letters offering mortgages.

What should these letters typical contain, who should they be addressed to, particularly if I will never / have never met the lender nor do I know who they might be.

Comment: Where are you? Practices differ...

Comment: oh sorry ill update that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of that, sounds weird. What would you write in the introduction letter that would affect the lender, and is not in your financial support? Whatever that might be - chances are that lender would be breaking an anti-discrimination law.

I now some real-estate agents in the area ask to write such letters to *sellers* to convince them to accept your offer, but I don't think it actually works all that much as well.

Anyway, regarding mortgage application - I would advise not writing any letter or providing any information the mortgage broker/loan officer didn't ask for. Some things are illegal for them to take into consideration and putting it in writing in the application may force them to decline just because they got exposed to that particular piece of information.

Comment: interesting thank you. I thought it sounded strange so I wanted to check